# If the chassis is at high potential and a human touches it, will he get shocked? The proposed circuit is for the cancellation of CM current

Tags: power-electronics, induction-motor, common-mode, motordriver, electric-vehicle

[image: Active Cancellation Circuit for CM current compensation with three-phase inverter]

[image]

This circuit is compensating the potential difference between the chassis and motor so the bearing current or leakage current cannot flow from motor to chassis to ground.

If the chassis is at a high potential and a human touches it, will he get shocked?

Comment: `high potential` relative to what?

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the circuit now.  high potential relative to ground. I am bit confuse, like if he is giving the voltage to the chassis, so the potential difference between motor neutral and chases become low, or zero and leakage current will not flow from motor to chassis, but what if a person touches the chassis then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that this is in an automotive context, where the chassis ground does not necessarily correspond to earth, and a real earth reference might very well not exist if you are not hooked up to a charger.

If the whole car is floating, then there is no risk of electric shock as you are either inside the car, where nothing but chassis potential is exposed, or outside the car, where you cannot complete the circuit to the battery anyway. Since we are dealing with DC voltages here, AC coupling is not even a risk.

The risk of an electrostatic discharge is always present, i.e. the car floats to several kV difference to earth, and when you touch it you get shocked, but this does not pose a health concern.

When the car is hooked up to a charger, I expect the charger to also expose a earth protection conductor, that provides an "absolute" reference to the whole system. This conductor should be hooked to the chassis on the car side, but again, this is more to protect the car itself rather than the humans.